# Migrating contents of Windows Phone 7.5 IsolatedStorage to Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

I have a Windows Phone 7.5 game that stores user progress in files located in IsolatedStorage. I am now planning to upgrade the code to WP 8.1. I don't want users to lose their progress when they update, therefore I need to somehow migrate user files from IsolatedStorage to new StorageFile/StorageFolder system after the update.

But, so far I could not find a way to access IsolatedStorage from a WP 8.1 app. Please tell me I am wrong. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The isolated storage folder is exposed via Windows Runtime as the LocalFolder. You access it the same way in Windows Phone 8 Silverlight apps and in Windows Phone Runtime apps.

```
StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
```

No migration is necessary. So long as your new app is published as an update to the existing one the user's data will maintain.

See: [Local folder best practices for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769544(v=vs.105).aspx) and [Accessing app data with the Windows Runtime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464917.aspx)

Comment: I have now verified that this is indeed the case - thanks! For once something is simple. To verify that IsolatedStorage data from 7.5 is in LocalFolder in 8.1 I used the beta test function of Windows Phone Store. I could not find any other way to simulate update from 7.5 to 8.1.